# Sum with Bernoulli numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers

How to prove that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k 2^k B_k = (2-2^n)B_n$$

In this sum, $B_n$ is the Bernoulli number with $B_1 = -\frac 1 2$. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your attempts and thoughts on the problem in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity that you want to verify can be rewritten as
$$\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{2^k B_k}{k!(n-k)!} = 2\frac{B_n}{n!} - \frac{2^nB_n}{n!}$$
From the ([standard](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html)) definition of Bernoulli numbers $B_n$, 
$g(z):=\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n$. Hence, the right hand side of the first equation above  corresponds to $n$-th coefficient of the power series 
\begin{align}
f(z)&=2g(z) - g(2z)\\
&=2\frac{z}{e^z-1}-\frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}\\
&=\frac{2z}{e^{2z} -1}e^z = g(2z)e^z\\
&=\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{B_n}{n!}2^nz^n\Big)\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n!}z^n\Big)\\
&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nz^n
\end{align}
where $c_n=\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{2^kB_k}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!}$ which is the left hands side of the identity we are trying to verify.

Comment: Could you please explain what I need to do next? I can't present this sum 2z*e^z/(e^(2z)-1) in series from n=0 to infinity.

Comment: I know these definitions. However, I can't find Cn/n! from sum 2z*e^z/(e^(2z)-1) in series, because I can't present this sum in series from n=0 to infinity.

Comment: There are no questions to this. How to find Cn? I want to find the coefficient, because it is the amount that I am trying to find. Therefore, I need to represent function 2z*e^z/(e^(2z)-1) as an infinite sum.

Comment: $\frac{2ze^z}{e^{2z}-1}=\frac{2z}{e^{2z}-1}e^z=g(2z)e^z$ where $g(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n$

Comment: Thank You Oliver Diaz. I understood, hooray!

Answer (score 4):

One possible way to demonstrate the thesis is through the B. Polynomials
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(n) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)2^{\,k} B_{\,k} }  = 2^{\,n} \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,n - k} B_{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2^{\,n} \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,k} B_{\,n - k} }  = 2^{\,n} B_{\,n} (1/2) \cr} 
$$

It is known that the values of [Bernoulli Polynomials at $x=1/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Symmetries))
are given by
$$
B_{\,n} (1/2) = \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n - 1} }} - 1} \right)B_{\,n} 
$$
and therefrom the demonstration that 
$$
S(n) = \left( {2 - 2^{\,n} } \right)B_{\,n} 
$$

The demonstration of the identity for $B_{\,n} (1/2)$ descends from the multiplicative 
identity
$$
\eqalign{
  & B_{\,n} (mx) = m^{\,n - 1} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{m - 1} {B_{\,n} (x + k/m)} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad B_{\,n} \left( {2 \cdot {1 \over 2}} \right) = B_{\,n} \left( 1 \right)
 = 2^{\,n - 1} \left( {B_{\,n} \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right) + B_{\,n} \left( {{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}} \right)} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad B_{\,n} \left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)
 = \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n - 1} }} - 1} \right)B_{\,n} \left( 1 \right) = \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n - 1} }} - 1} \right)B_{\,n} \left( 0 \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{1 \over {2^{\,n - 1} }} - 1} \right)B_{\,n} \quad \left| {\;0 \le n} \right. \cr} 
$$

and you can find a proof of the multiplicative identity
in [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013616), which is not .. "very complicated".

Comment: Ok, how i can prove that (i don't understand how to write formulas here, but i will try): $$B_n(1/2)=(1/(2^(n-1))-1)B_n&&?

Comment: That requires to know things about Bernoulli polynomials...I still think that what you need to prove the identity requires only basic knowledge of product of analytic functions and the use of the definition of Bernoulli numbers $B_n$. In standard complex analysis textbooks, they are defined from the derivative at $0$ of the function by $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$, that is $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n$

Comment: @Katy: added for proving the identity for $B_n(1/2)$, I wish that meets your expectations, and in any case it is good to brush it up for me and other readers here.

Comment: @OliverDiaz:  you can, more politely, sustain the advantage of your answer inside its context. Yet criticism is always welcome.

Comment: @ G Cab Thank you very much. I understood your proof, hooray :))

Comment: Stop, @G Cab, why $B_n(0)=B_n(1)$? I know that this possible only when n not 1.

Comment: @Katy: right, but for $n=1$  the factor in front $2^{(-n+1)}-1 $ is null, so the identity is true for all $n$

Comment: Ok, thank you))